# How can I get connect to a specific WIFI network from ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have seen some posts that discussed how to connect to WIFI without specifying SSID, or build an apk to connect to WIFI. Is there a way to connect to a specific WIFI solely from ADB commands?

Technically, I am interested in ADB commands:

1) List all available WIFI networks

2) Connect/Switch to a specific network.

Comment: Did you solve your problem without installing any obscure app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this tool: https://github.com/yandex-qatools/android-wifitool

It's as easy as

```
adb install wifitool-debug.apk
adb shell am broadcast  -n ru.yandex.qatools.wifitool/.Connect -e ssid MyNetwork
```

No root required. It can retry connection attempts if necessary and it waits for Wifi to get connected.

Comment: While using the app it always show "Fail: Unable to remove existing network". I get the log using **adb devices | findstr "WifiTool"**

Answer (score 0):

if your device is rooted, you can connect to ssid using `adb shell wpa_cli`. 
Please see [wpa_cli help](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_utilities%2Fw%2Fwpa_cli.html)

Answer (score 0):

With a non device root is it possible to use something like

```
adb install -r C:\Apps\Agent.apk
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
adb shell input keyevent 20
adb shell input keyevent 19
adb shell input keyevent 23
```

Then some how connect to a specific network (Non Rooted device)?